# What is the computational complexity of linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity

What is the computational complexity of solving a linear program with $m$ constraints in $n$ variables?

Comment: There are ([weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Open_problems_and_recent_work))[polynomial times algorithms that find the solutions by moving a point in the interior of the simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar%27s_algorithm). I don't know what is the minimum exponent possible.

Comment: Though it’s worth mentioning that the most common linear programming algorithm—the simplex—method, os exponential in its worst case.

Comment: Thank you, but here I am speaking about the theoretical complexity of linear programming not algorithms. For example, it is known (to the best of my knowledge) that solving a quadratic program is equivalent to solving a system of linear equations, so the complexity of quadratic programming is about O(n^3). Is there any similar result for linear programming ?

Comment: The result due to Spielman and Teng has explained why simplex method is efficient in practice https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0111050.pdf Title : Smoothed Analysis of Algorithms: Why the Simplex Algorithm usually Takes Polynomial Time.

Comment: This lecture notes contain a detailed history of LP algorithm in theory, https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ecprice/courses/331/slides/04-20.pdf

Answer (score 13):

The best possible (I believe) is by Michael Cohen, Yin Tat Lee, and Zhao Song:
Solving linear program in the current matrix multiplication time. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07896
(STOC 2019)
Hope this helps.

Comment: The result by Cohen, Lee and Song has been reproduced via a different method, see this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.04447.pdf

Comment: The 2+1/6 has been improved to 2+1/18 in a recent work by Shunhua Jiang, Zhao Song, Omri Weinstein, and Hengjie Zhang. The title is Faster Dynamic Matrix Inverse for Faster LPs, and the link is https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.07470.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Brand's 2020 result derandomized the Cohen, Lee and Song result.
Here is the link
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.11957.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much for all these useful pointers; this is an impressive set of recent improvements that I was not aware of. I am wondering what model of computation is assumed in these papers? I cannot seem to find this explicitly stated in these papers, probably because there is some implicit standard in this branch of literature. I am guessing the assumption is a RAM model, but I'm not sure what the details are of this model: What set of basic arithmetic operations are supported and how long do they take?